# Handling UIButtons iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've been watching the iOS lectures(by Paul Hegerty) from Winter 2013 and I can't seem to wrap my head around why this second line of code is necessary in the Matchisimo program. If I comment it out, the program crashes, but if I leave it in, it works fine.

```
[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Fails at this line:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate class]));
}
```

Error given if the second line is commented out:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 47 beyond bounds [0 .. 46]'
```

Card contents:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *contents;
```

Update UI:

```
- (void)updateUI
{
    for (UIButton *cardButton in self.cardButtons) {
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];

        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];

        cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
        cardButton.enabled = !card.isUnPlayable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the button disabled on launch?

Comment: Any error messages on crash?

Comment: There is no code indicating that it is.

Comment: 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 47 beyond bounds [0 .. 46]'

Comment: Can we have a look at the code behind card.contents and the button creation in its entirety?

Comment: You need to post more code.  I looked for the project you are referring to, and cannot find it here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2013-winter

Comment: Is what I posted not sufficient? You must go through the Lecture 3 slides to find this code.

Comment: @John, the second line of code just sets the button title on its disabled state. Thus, when two cards are matched, the state of the button is set to disabled and you are still able to see the rank and suit. If you remove the second line, you will see the 'apple logo' instead of card contents on matched cards. It will definitely not crash the app. There is something wrong with number of cards. At which line of code does the app crash?

Comment: It just goes to     @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate class]));
    }, doesn't give me anything else.

Comment: @John I think there is something wrong with the deck. There should be 52 objects (bounds 0...51), but instead it seems like there are 47 in your case. So when the code tries to draw a card from the last five, it crashes. I also followed the course, and uploaded my code to github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/tolgamorf/Matchismo), maybe it will help. (It has commits for each addition from the lectures)

Comment: I just ran the same code 4 times and it started working. Also, it gave a different index error every time I ran it.

Answer (score 3):

Commenting this line `[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];` does not cause a crash for any reason.

This is the line `[self.game cardAtIndex:[self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton]];` causing a crash related to an index out of bounds. Basically you have more cardButtons than `self.game` has cards.

You can wrap it with this to prevent a crash but should look for the deeper underlying problem for why an extra button is created.

```
int buttonIndex = [self.cardButtons indexOfObject:cardButton];
if (self.game.count > buttonIndex) {
    Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];

    cardButton.selected = card.isFaceUp;
    cardButton.enabled = !card.isUnPlayable;
}
```

Comment: Why would it fail here: @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CardGameAppDelegate class]));
}?

Comment: That is just the entrance point for you app, not where it is actually failing. Google Xcode Exception Breakpoint and add one of those to your project. It will then stop on the actual failed line.

Comment: I have an answer somewhere with screenshots but I can't seem to find it. But here is a small screenshot of what to look for. http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1/add-exception-breakpoint

Comment: Thanks for the breakpoint help, that's what I needed. It turns out I was using & instead of % to determine the index. That's why it worked once and not other times.

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction :) Happy Coding!